# Branch through maven from subversion tag with correct developerConnection

Tags: maven, svn, maven-release-plugin

I am trying to create a branch from a tag with maven but the *developerConnection* property is not updated. How do I do this through maven or editing the *pom.xml* file manually?

We use subversion for scm and maven for build/release. I want to create a branch from the latest tag (release). We will use the branch for maintenance of the code, including bug fixes, and continue developing on the trunk. (I know that discussion of developing on trunk versus on branch is involved, and I don't want to open that up.)

When I use release:branch to create the branch, the developerConnection property refers to the tag that I checked out of to create my working copy. I want it to point to the branch.

1. I checked out the latest tag. (*foo-80.0.8*)
2. From the command line in the working copy directory of that tag, I ran:

   ```
   mvn release:branch -DbranchName=foo-80.0.8.1.x -DupdateWorkingCopyVersions=false
   ```

   (The *.1.x* refers to the *1* st branch with *x* as a placeholder indicator for branch version.)

In the resulting *pom.xml* in the branch on the repository, the *developerConnection* property was set to
*...Foo/tags/foo-80.0.8* (I omitted the beginning of the URL to prevent the automatic hyperlink.) I want it to be *...Foo/branches/foo-80.0.8.1.x*

I tried again, but this time, I edited the *pom.xml* file, and changed *developerConnection* to *...Foo/branches/foo-80.0.8.1.x*. After running `mvn release:branch ...`, *developerConnection* in the *pom.xml* file still pointed to the tag.

**UPDATE:**

I took @twomey1's suggestion. (Thanks!) Now *developerConnection* points to `...\tags\foo-80.0.8.1.x` which is not the original tag (*good*), but that tag doesn't exist (*bad*). I checked out a fresh copy of the new branch, modified *pom.xml* to point to the branch, and committed the change. When I tried `mvn release:prepare` I got this error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal 
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.0-beta-7:prepare (default-cli) on
project foo: You don't have a SNAPSHOT project in the reactor projects list.
```

**UPDATE:**

@twomey1's comment about SNAPSHOT helped. Using -DupdateVersionsToSnapshot on the command line, I got release:prepare to go forward but there still seems to be confusion with tags and branches. Again, my workflow:

1. Run `svn checkout https:.../tags/foo-80.0.8`.
2. Run `mvn -DupdateVersionsToSnapshot=true -DupdateBranchVersions=true 
   -DupdateWorkingCopyVersions=false -DbranchName=foo-80.0.8.1 release:branch` from the working copy of the **tag** that was just checked out.
3. Run `svn checkout https:.../branches/foo-80.0.8.1` from the parent directory of the working copy.
4. Run `mvn release:prepare` from the working copy of the **branch** that was just checked out.

Then I get a svn error passed from maven that tag *foo-80.0.8.1* already exists. I want to create a release from the branch which should not conflict. The *developerConnection* property still points to *...\tags\foo-80.0.8.1* which doesn't exist.

**UPDATE:**

I repeated with this difference, I added .1 to the end of the release version, the SCM release tag, and the portion of the development version before SNAPSHOT. This seems to work. I did this during `mvn release:prepare`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official release plugin documentation

> By default, the POM in the new branch keeps the same version as the
>   local working copy, and the local POM is incremented to the next
>   revision. If you want to update versions in the new branch and not in
>   the working copy, run:
>
> mvn release:branch -DbranchName=my-branch -DupdateBranchVersions=true
>   -DupdateWorkingCopyVersions=false
>
> Note: This can be useful if you want to create a branch from a tag

http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/branch.html

I think you are just missing -updateBranchVersions=true from your command

Comment: Thanks, @ctwomey1. That was a step in the right direction. Instead of pointing to the original tag, now it points to _.../tags/foo-80.0.8.1.x_ That tag doesn't exist, but the branch does exist. Maybe it is not changing _tags_ to _branches_. I checked out the new branch as a separate working copy and edited the _pom.xml_ file manually. When I ran `maven release:prepare`, I received the error message `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.0-beta-7:prepare (default-cli) on project foo: You don't have a SNAPSHOT project in the reactor projects list.`

Comment: When cutting a release with release:prepare your version number must end in -snapshot.  The release plugin will go through the needed steps to change a snapshot to an actual release

Comment: Thanks, @ctwomey1! With SNAPSHOT, it let me do the release, but it still seems to get mixed up between the branch and tags. See update to original question.